# How to only return the needed validated values using Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

Is there a way to only get the values back from `yup` that matches the provided schema?

For example I have this data

```
const profileData = {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe',
    age: 53,
    extra: 'An extra property'
}
```

And this is my schema

```
const profileValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    firstname: yup.string().required(),
    lastname: yup.string().required(),
    age: yup.number().required(),
});
```

When I validate this schema and get the values back I would expect that the property `extra` is removed from the values which is not.

```
const values = await profileValidationSchema.validate(profileData, {
    abortEarly: false,
    stripUnknown: true,
});
```

Is there another way to strip the values that are not provided in the schema?

Comment: weird, when I used this exact code, `values` no longer has `extra`

Comment: my codesandbox of it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-mahavira-1xm3zy?file=/src/yuper.ts

Comment: Your yuper.ts file seems to be empty

Comment: Can you share your `yuper.ts` file?

Answer (score 0):

`stripUnknown` is indeed a solution.

I have 2 other proposals as solution.

You can use `object.noUnknown`

> Validate that the object value only contains keys specified in shape,
> pass false as the first argument to disable the check. Restricting
> keys to known, also enables stripUnknown option, when not in strict
> mode.

```
const profileData = {
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  age: 53,
  extra: "An extra property",
};

 
const profileValidationSchema = yup
  .object()
  .noUnknown(true) // validate keys
  .shape({
        firstname: yup.string().required(),
        lastname: yup.string().required(),
        age: yup.number().required(),
      });
const values = await profileValidationSchema.validate(profileData, {
  abortEarly: false,
});

    /*
    value will be  {
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "age": 53
     }
    */
enter code here
```

refer to Yup [documentations](https://github.com/jquense/yup) for more information

OR - Usually what I do is that I predefine the shape of the `YUP` validation schema.
We can benefit from predefined schema by operating a simple iteration as in the following

```
 const profileData = {
      firstname: "John",
      lastname: "Doe",
      age: 53,
      extra: "An extra property",
    };
const shape = {
  firstname: yup.string().required(),
  lastname: yup.string().required(),
  age: yup.number().required(),
};
const profileValidationSchema = yup
  .object()
  .shape({ ...shape });

const values = await profileValidationSchema.validate(profileData, {
  abortEarly: false,
});


let finalResult = {};
    for (const key in shape) {
      if (values[key]) {
        finalResult = { ...finalResult, [key]: values[key] };
      }
    }
/*
finalResult will be  {
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "age": 53
 }
*/
```

Comment: I worked a little bit further on my app this weekend and I need to take it one step further. Is there a way to strip properties like if they are in the schema but behind a condition?  For example: the property `username` is required when `account_name_method` is `username` but may not be saved when `account_name_method` is `email`


Yup schema lines:
`account_name_method: yup.string().required('required_field').oneOf(['email', 'username']),
    username: yup.string().when('account_name_method', { is: 'username', then: yup.string().required('required_field') })`